# Unable to scrape tabular data in NSE

Tags: python, web-scraping, data-analysis

I am trying to scrape the Advances/Declines from NSE website - https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_market.htm

Advances/Declines is in tabular format in the HTML. But I am not able to retrieve the actual numerical value that is displayed in the site.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = "https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_market.htm"
webpage = requests.get(url);
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage.content, "html.parser");
for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
  advance = tr.find_all('td')
  print(advance)
```

[image]

I am only able to get an empty value or NONE. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. When I inspect the element in the website, I see the numerical values 978, 904 but in Spyder, the values in these elements are displayed with a hyphen. Can someone please help?

[image]

Comment: it can uses JavaScript to load data later but `requests`/`BeautifulSoup` can't run `JavaScript`

Comment: Please note that the `nse` tag is used for questions about non-standard evaluation (as explained in the tag description). I am removing the tag, since this question is about `stockquotes` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This page uses `JavaScript` to load these information but `requests`/`BeautifulSoup` can't run `JavaScript`.

Using `DevTools` in `Chrome`/`Firefox` (tab `Network`, filter `xhr`) I found url used by `JavaScript` to load it as `JSON` data so I don't have to even use `BeautifulSoup` to get it.

```
import requests

url = 'https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_analysis/changePercentage.json'
r = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
data = r.json()
print(data['rows'][0]['advances'])
print(data['rows'][0]['declines'])
print(data['rows'][0]['unchanged'])
print(data['rows'][0]['total'])
```

**BTW:** It doesn't send data without `User-Agent`

Comment: Many thanks for the quick response. Works like a charm :) I didnt know that beautiful soup doesnt support javascript. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: BTW: Other examples for `nseindia.com` on [GitHub/furas/python-examples/__scraping__](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/__scraping__)

Comment: Thanks again. I will take a detailed look into your GitHub :)